# Producing matrix arrays in TikZ with overlaid numbers

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrays, foreach

How can I produce a figure like below in `TikZ`? I would also like to overlay desired numbers in all the cells. I have been able to produce till now a similar figure but with the same color in all the background matrices and with no control on the cell entries:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{choices}{{U}{0}}
\foreach \z in {0,2.5,5}{ 
\begin{scope}[xshift=\z*0.02cm] 
\foreach \x in {0,...,3}{ 
\foreach \y in {0,...,3}{ 
\node[fill=yellow,minimum size=1cm-\pgflinewidth,draw] (n-\x-\y-\z) at (\x+.5,\y+.5,\z) {\pgfmathrandomitem{\mynum}{choices}\mynum}; } }    \end{scope} } 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). We suggest you to show a minimal working example [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) on what you have worked so far, so we can help you further.

Comment: Please add the code to you question itself. You can edit it.

Comment: What are the "desired numbers"? With your code you get 0 or U in each square, if you want empty squares you have to remove `\pgfmathrandomitem{\mynum}{choices}\mynum`.

Answer (score 4):

Using the `matrix` :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{choices}{{U}{0}}
  \foreach \z/\c in {0/blue,2.5/blue!66,5/blue!33}{ 
    \begin{scope}[xshift=\z] 
      \foreach \x in {0,...,3}{ 
        \foreach \y in {0,...,3}{ 
          \node[fill=\c,minimum size=1cm-\pgflinewidth,draw]
          (n-\x-\y-\z) at
          (\x,\y,\z) {\pgfmathrandomitem{\mynum}{choices}\mynum}; } }
    \end{scope} } 
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \s/\c in {0cm/blue,1cm/blue!66,2cm/blue!33}{
    \begin{scope}[xshift=-\s,yshift=-\s]
    \matrix [matrix of nodes, ampersand replacement=\&,
    nodes={rectangle, anchor=center, draw=black!40, fill=\c,
      minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm},
    row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    nodes in empty cells]
    {
      1 \& 2 \& \& \\
      \& \& \& \\
      \& \& \& \\
      \& \& \& \\
    };
  \end{scope}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]